# membership provider

Tags: membership, provider

how do i setup my web.config to use Forms authentication, Set The Membership provider  to ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and use the built-in login control. so that I can log into my web application using a valid active directory username and password???

Answer (score 2):

Check out this walk through for the [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx).